# Issues with padding in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout

```
<View
  android:id="@+id/first_sep"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dip"
  android:paddingTop="100dip"
  android:layout_below="@id/calculate"
  android:background="#FFCCCCCC" />
```

I have this `View` in a `RelativeLayout` and the `android:paddingTop` property doesn't seem to work. Tried it with various values and still the View lies close to the Button "calculate".

Comment: try to use android:layout_marginTop

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As MGS indicates, you probably want `android:layout_marginTop`, or perhaps `android:layout_height=101dip`. I am uncertain if padding has any meaning on a generic `View`. If it is supported, it certainly will have no difference than simply setting the height to include the padding, since padding is considered part of the background calcluations.

For space between a widget and an adjacent widget, use margins. For space between the edges of a widget and its contents (e.g., between the edge of a `Button` and its caption), use padding. In the case of a transparent background, these will visually be identical. In the case of a non-transparent background, they will be substantially different visually.